# Weird Tomcat outage, possibly related to maxConnections

Tags: linux, tomcat, tomcat7

In my company we experienced a serious problem today: our production server went down.  Most people accessing our software via a browser were unable to get a connection, however people who had already been using the software were able to continue using it. Even our hot standby server was unable to communicate with the production server, which it does using HTTP, not even going out to the broader internet. The whole time the server was accessible via ping and ssh, and in fact was quite underloaded - it's normally running at 5% CPU load and it was even lower at this time. We do almost no disk i/o.

A few days after the problem started we have a new variation:  port 443 (HTTPS) is responding but port 80 stopped responding. The server load is very low. Immediately after restarting tomcat, port 80 started responding again.

We're using tomcat7, with maxThreads="200", and using maxConnections=10000. We serve all data out of main memory, so each HTTP request completes very quickly, but we have a large number of users doing very simple interactions (this is high school subject selection). But it seems very unlikely we would have 10,000 users all with their browser open on our page at the same time.

My question has several parts:

- Is it likely that the "maxConnections" parameter is the cause of our woes?
- Is there any reason not to set "maxConnections" to a ridiculously high value e.g. 100,000?  (i.e. what's the cost of doing so?)
- Does tomcat output a warning message anywhere once it hits the "maxConnections" message?  (We didn't notice anything).
- Is it possible there's an OS limit we're hitting?  We're using CentOS 6.4 (Linux) and "ulimit -f" says "unlimited".  (Do firewalls understand the concept of Tcp/Ip connections? Could there be a limit elsewhere?)
- What happens when tomcat hits the "maxConnections" limit? Does it try to close down some inactive connections?  If not, why not?  I don't like the idea that our server can be held to ransom by people having their browsers on it, sending the keep-alive's to keep the connection open.

But the main question is, "How do we fix our server?"

More info as requested by Stefan and Sharpy:

- Our clients communicate directly with this server
- TCP connections were in some cases immediately refused and in other cases timed out
- The problem is evident even connecting my browser to the server within the network, or with the hot standby server - also in the same network - unable to do database replication messages which normally happens over HTTP
- IPTables - yes, IPTables6 - I don't think so. Anyway, there's nothing between my browser and the server when I test after noticing the problem.

More info:
It really looked like we had solved the problem when we realised we were using the default Tomcat7 setting of BIO, which has one thread per connection, and we had maxThreads=200. In fact 'netstat -an' showed about 297 connections, which matches 200 + queue of 100. So we changed this to NIO and restarted tomcat. Unfortunately the same problem occurred the following day.  It's possible we misconfigured the server.xml.

The server.xml and extract from catalina.out is available here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sxgd0fbzyvuldy7/AACZWoBKXNKfXjsSmkgkVgW_a?dl=0

More info:
I did a load test.  I'm able to create 500 connections from my development laptop, and do an HTTP GET 3 times on each, without any problem. Unless my load test is invalid (the Java class is also in the above link).

Comment: There should be a logs directory in the main Tomcat directory where errors get reported.

Comment: Adding the following information to your question might help with finding an answer: Are your clients communicating directly with your Tomcat, or via a web server that forwards requests to it? When you write "were unable to get a connection" and "port 80 stopped responding", do you mean that the TCP connections were refused, or that there was no response from the server at all (i.e. there was a timeout waiting for the server's response)? Is there any kind of router/packet filter between your server and the standby server?

Comment: Can you post the tomcat error logs as @Jaydee said beforehand, they would greatly help. Also, do you have IPTables or IP6Tables enabled on the server? Do you have any DDoS/DoS firewalls/filters through your server provider or ISP and have you asked them if they have any limits on this? Lastly, what response do you get when trying to connect via :80 ?

Comment: Info added as requested.  Absolutely no indication in the catalina.out log file. I'll try to get wireshark logs.

Comment: Are there resources that are getting locked and not released? Anywhere the code is using synchronization in a suspicious way? any resources you're wrapping in a lock?  
It certainly sounds like something's getting monopolized and that you've ruled out everything else. You might be able to find the held resources with a heap dump (good luck with that ;) or jvisualvm.

Comment: what's in tomcat's access log when people cannot get responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

- Use the NIO connector instead of the default BIO connector
- Set "maxConnections" to something suitable e.g. 10,000
- Encourage users to use HTTPS so that intermediate proxy servers can't turn 100 page requests into 100 tcp connections.
- Check for threads hanging due to deadlock problems, e.g. with a stack dump (kill -3)
- (If applicable and if you're not already doing this, write your client app to use the one connection for multiple page requests).

The long answer:

We were using the BIO connector instead of NIO connector. The difference between the two is that BIO is "one thread per connection" and NIO is "one thread can service many connections".  So increasing "maxConnections" was irrelevant if we didn't also increase "maxThreads", which we didn't, because we didn't understand the BIO/NIO difference.

To change it to NIO, put this in the  element in server.xml:
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"

From what I've read, there's no benefit to using BIO so I don't know why it's the default. We were only using it because it was the default and we assumed the default settings were reasonable and we didn't want to become experts in tomcat tuning to the extent that we now have.

HOWEVER:  Even after making this change, we had a similar occurrence:  on the same day, HTTPS became unresponsive even while HTTP was working, and then a little later the opposite occurred.  Which was a bit depressing.  We checked in 'catalina.out' that in fact the NIO connector was being used, and it was.  So we began a long period of analysing 'netstat' and wireshark.  We noticed some periods of high spikes in the number of connections - in one case up to 900 connections when the baseline was around 70.  These spikes occurred when we synchronised our databases between the main production server and the "appliances" we install at each customer site (schools).  The more we did the synchronisation, the more we caused outages, which caused us to do even more synchronisations in a downward spiral.

What seems to be happening is that the NSW Education Department proxy server splits our database synchronisation traffic into multiple connections so that 1000 page requests become 1000 connections, and furthermore they are not closed properly until the TCP 4 minute timeout.  The proxy server was only able to do this because we were using HTTP. The reason they do this is presumably load balancing - they thought by splitting the page requests across their 4 servers, they'd get better load balancing. When we switched to HTTPS, they are unable to do this and are forced to use just one connection.  So that particular problem is eliminated - we no longer see a burst in the number of connections.

People have suggested increasing "maxThreads".  In fact this would have improved things but this is not the 'proper' solution - we had the default of 200, but at any given time, hardly any of these were doing anything, in fact hardly any of these were even allocated to page requests.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell for sure without hands-on debugging but one of the first things I would check would be the file descriptor limit (that's `ulimit -n`). TCP connections consume file descriptors, and depending on which implementation is in use, nio connections that do polling using `SelectableChannel` may eat several file descriptors per open socket.

To check if this is the cause:

- Find Tomcat PIDs using `ps`
- Check the `ulimit` the process runs with: `cat /proc/<PID>/limits | fgrep 'open files'`
- Check how many descriptors are actually in use: `ls /proc/<PID>/fd | wc -l`

If the number of used descriptors is significantly lower than the limit, something else is the cause of your problem. But if it is equal or very close to the limit, it's this limit which is causing issues. In this case you should increase the limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` for the user with whose account Tomcat is running and restart the process from a newly opened shell, check using `/proc/<PID>/limits` if the new limit is actually used, and see if Tomcat's behavior is improved.

Comment: ulimit -n   gives 65536.  The number of connections as reported by 'netstat' is obviously nowhere near this.  And 'ulimit -f' is 'unlimited'.  The '/proc' command gives:  Max open files            65535                65535                files

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have a direct answer to solve your problem, I'd like to offer my methods to find what's wrong.

Intuitively there are 3 assumptions:

1. If your clients hold their connections and never release, it is quite possible your server hits the max connection limit even there is no communications.
2. The non-responding state can also be reached via various ways such as bugs in the server-side code.
3. The hardware conditions should not be ignored.

To locate the cause of this problem, you'd better try to replay the scenario in a testing environment. Perform more comprehensive tests and record more detailed logs,  including but not limited:

- Unit tests, esp. logic blocks using transactions, threading and synchronizations.
- Stress-oriented tests. Try to simulate all the user behaviors you can come up with and their combinations and test them in a massive batch mode. ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj125126.aspx))
- More specified Logging. Trace client behaviors and analysis what happened exactly before the server stopped responding.
- Replace a server machine and see if it will still happen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you're not hitting the maxThreads limit?  Have you tried changing it?

These days browsers limit simultaneous connections to a max of 4 per hostname/ip, so if you have 50 simultaneous browsers, you could easily hit that limit.  Although hopefully your webapp responds quickly enough to handle this.  Long polling has become popular these days (until websockets are more prevalent), so you may have 200 long polls.

Another cause could be if you use HTTP[S] for app-to-app communication (that is, no browser involved).  Sometimes app writers are sloppy and create new connections for performing multiple tasks in parallel, causing TCP and HTTP overhead.  Double check that you are not getting an inflood of requests.  Log files can usually help you on this, or you can use wireshark to count the number of HTTP requests or HTTP[S] connections.  If possible, modify your API to handle multiple API calls in one HTTP request.

Related to the last one, if you have many HTTP/1.1 requests going across one connection, and intermediate proxy may be splitting them into multiple connections for load balancing purposes.  Sounds crazy I know, but I've seen it happen.

Lastly, some crawl bots ignore the crawl delay set in robots.txt.  Again, log files and/or wireshark can help you determine this.

Overall, run more experiments with more changes.  maxThreads, https, etc. before jumping to conclusions with maxConnections.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to debug the application using Apache JMeter for number of connection and use Jconsole or Zabbix to look for heap space or thread dump for tomcat server.

Nio Connector of Apache tomcat can have maximum connections of 10000 but I don't think thats a good idea to provide that much connection to one instance of tomcat better way to do this is to run multiple instance of tomcat.

In my view best way for Production server: To Run Apache http server in front and point your tomcat instance to that http server using AJP connector.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've never heard someone recommend run 2 tomcats. Apart from the fact that our memory-based database won't work with this, how can this be an advantage unless it's using a different physical server?

Comment: We can run multiple tomcat instances on different port and configuration like JVM memory for same war on one machine that will leads to maximum utilisation of physical server. Multiple physical server can point to http server.

Comment: But *why* does it improve utilisation of physical server?

Comment: we can utilise more ram of server as well that will give us scalability. Also with more tomcat instance we can have less chance of failure and you can utilise more CPU. how much cpu and memory can a single tomcat instance utilise but if you have multiple instance, its quite simple it will improve utilisation

Comment: I believe you're mistaken.  Any tomcat instance can use as much memory as you give it (see -Xmx) and as much CPU as the machine has. If you have 16Gb RAM then you can give 15Gb to a single tomcat instance (leave 1Gb for the OS), OR you can give 7.5Gb to each of 2 tomcat instances, but there is no benefit, only complications to having 2 tomcat instances.

Comment: If I have a physical server with huge memory, then I think we should better create more instances of tomcat rather then creating multiple VM instances because VM also cost memory.You can go to this link:https://groups.google.com/a/openmrs.org/forum/#!msg/implementers/71aChxU75_0/vCWheAo4RjkJ